# при загрузке страницы скролл на том же месте что и на предыдущей странице

Tags: javascript, html

Вопрос в заголовке, почему такое может быть? Якорей нету у url, хотелось бы что бы при загрузке страницы скролл был в самом вверху, пробовал так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 1);
});
```

Все равно страница скролится на то место что и на предыдущей странице

Comment: `$(window).on('load', function() { // тут ваш setTimeout со скроллом });`

Comment: тоже пробовал не работает в моем случае

Comment: А других скриптов нет?

Comment: Есть но не могу понять что именно принимает скролл предыдущей страницы....